How is slashing in ethereum actually implemented?
In ethtereum, if a validator missbehaves, their funds are confiscated/slashed. But how is that actually implemented? Do the other validators vote and if theres a majority, some validator looses his funds? Or is it more technically implemented? How does it work on the blockchain level?

There are three types of misbehavior that can trigger a slashing: double vote, double proposition, and surround vote.
The punishment operates in the same way each time:

First, the misbehavior is enacted.
Another validator (called the whistleblower) notices it and sends proof of the misbehavior.
When the proof is included in a block, all validators make the appropriate change to the faulty validator's stake.

Example: Double Vote
Let's say that a faulty validator sends 2 different attestations during the same epoch.
A validator seeing this slashing behavior will send proof of the misbehavior with the two conflicting attestations:
class AttesterSlashing(Container):
    attestation_1: IndexedAttestation
    attestation_2: IndexedAttestation

This is then included in a block. When the block is processed by the validators, a verification is done to check whether it is actually a slashing behavior:
def is_slashable_attestation_data(data_1: AttestationData, data_2: AttestationData) -> bool:
    return (
        /* Double vote */
        (data_1 != data_2 and data_1.target.epoch == data_2.target.epoch)
    )

If it is, the validator is slashed according to the function:
def slash_validator(state: BeaconState,
                    slashed_index: ValidatorIndex,
                    whistleblower_index: ValidatorIndex=None) -> None:
    validator = state.validators[slashed_index]
    validator.slashed = True
    slashing_penalty = validator.effective_balance / MIN_SLASHING_PENALTY_QUOTIENT_BELLATRIX
    decrease_balance(state, slashed_index, slashing_penalty)

    whistleblower_reward = Gwei(validator.effective_balance / WHISTLEBLOWER_REWARD_QUOTIENT)
    proposer_reward = Gwei(whistleblower_reward * PROPOSER_WEIGHT / WEIGHT_DENOMINATOR)
    increase_balance(state, proposer_index, proposer_reward)
    increase_balance(state, whistleblower_index, Gwei(whistleblower_reward - proposer_reward))

This function decreases the stake of the faulty validator and rewards the whistleblower and the proposer for discovering and including the proof of the misbehavior.

The code is simplified for the example. You can check the official specifications here and the commented specifications here.

Staking is a crucial component of Ethereum's Proof-of-Stake (PoS) mechanism, enabling the network to reach consensus on which blocks to produce in a decentralized manner. Staking incentivizes network participants to contribute to network coordination and security, earning rewards for their contributions. Slashing is a fundamental role in maintaining the security and integrity of Ethereum's PoS mechanism, designed to deter validators from engaging in dishonest behavior or breaching their obligations.
There are three ways a validator can be slashed, all of which amount to a dishonest proposal or attestation of blocks: proposing and signing two different blocks for the same slot, attesting to a block that "surrounds" another one, or attesting to two candidates for the same block ("double voting"). Slashing penalties are the same for all slashable offenses and have multiple components.
A majority of slashing events occur unintentionally when two different validator's clients use the same validator key. Consensys Staking aims to mitigate slashing risks by ensuring that validator keys are generated using a distinct seed phrase, ensuring each key is unique. staking is a vital component of Ethereum's PoS ecosystem, providing economic incentives for network participants to contribute to network coordination and security. Slashing penalties are designed to deter malicious behavior and prevent coordinated attacks on the Ethereum network.
This process can result in financial losses, reputation damage, network participation restrictions, opportunity cost, and market volatility. Staking slashing can lead to partial or complete reduction of tokens, affecting a staker's investment value. It can also damage a stakeholder's reputation within the network, impacting their ability to attract delegations or participate in future staking opportunities.
Network participation restrictions can result from slashing, preventing stakers from earning rewards or contributing to network security. Staking slashing can also result in opportunity cost, as stakers may miss out on potential staking rewards if their tokens were not locked. Market volatility can also increase the financial impact of slashing during a market downturn.
The mechanism of staking slashing involves validators and stakers depositing tokens as collateral to participate in the staking process. If a validator behaves maliciously or violates the network's rules, the network detects the misconduct and initiates the slashing process, reducing the validator's collateral. Stakers who delegate tokens to malicious validators may also face partial slashing. Slashing penalties serve as a deterrent against dishonest behavior, ensuring network security and trustworthiness.

Yes but what is the technical mechanism (smart contract? Majoraity vote?) That implments this process. What is the actual order of events that make the slashing happen?

Your answer is a bit too long. It seems written by an AI bot. There are no details about the Ethereum implementation. Then mention a product Consensys Staking only a tangential subject.
